# Use of an Image as GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I am getting latitudes and longitudes from json and i want to show them on a map. 
I've done it using normal way like by using googleMap and Overlays.
but actually i want it to be like below image.

[image]

I've searched and got some hints like showing map in webView and using Javascript. 
but don't find any tutorial or sample code.

Its a static image and will not be zoom in or out. just i wants to put location coordinates on image.

so my question is, is that possible to have an image as a gooleMap?

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Which Maps API version do you use? Or are you fixed to an webview/js solution?

Comment: i'm using 2.2 and up.. i like defau1t and VokilaM solution i will definetly try that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to override ImageView#onDraw() and draw location points on top of an image. The main task is to translate coordinates from geo space to ImageView space. Therefore, you need to know bounds of your map image in geo space.

I made a screenshot of USA in Google Maps. Using `Right click -> What is here?` menu I found geo bounds of my screenshot. Also I picked some test points around the country border.

Here's a simple example. Custom ImageView:

```
public class MapImageView extends ImageView {
    private float latitudeTop, latitudeBottom, longitudeRight, longitudeLeft;
    private List<Float> points = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private Paint pointPaint;
    private Matrix pointMatrix = new Matrix();

    public MapImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        pointPaint = new Paint();
        pointPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        pointPaint.setStrokeCap(Cap.ROUND);
        pointPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        pointPaint.setStrokeWidth(8.0f);
    }

    public void setBounds(float latitudeTop, float latitudeBottom, float longitudeLeft, float longitudeRight) {
        this.latitudeTop = latitudeTop;
        this.latitudeBottom = latitudeBottom;
        this.longitudeLeft = longitudeLeft;
        this.longitudeRight = longitudeRight;
    }

    public void addPoint(float latitude, float longitude) {
        points.add(longitude);
        points.add(latitude);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        pointMatrix.reset();
        pointMatrix.postTranslate(-longitudeLeft, -latitudeTop);
        pointMatrix.postScale(
                getMeasuredWidth()/(longitudeRight-longitudeLeft), 
                getMeasuredHeight()/(latitudeBottom-latitudeTop));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawPoints(mapPoints(), pointPaint);
    }

    private float[] mapPoints() {
        float[] pts = new float[points.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
            pts[i] = points.get(i);
        }

        pointMatrix.mapPoints(pts);

        return pts;
    }
}
```

In your layout:

```
<com.example.stackoverflow.MapImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/map"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Note that `scaleType="fitXY"` is important, because coordinates are mapped to ImageView bounds, not the map picture.

In your activity:

```
MapImageView mapView = (MapImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_map);
mapView.setBounds(52.734778f, 19.979026f, -130.78125f, -62.402344f);

mapView.addPoint(42.163403f,-70.839844f);
mapView.addPoint(42.163403f,-70.839844f);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: it worked! but dont get pins at exact points they are approximate to location, what i need to do to get pins at exact place on map.

Comment: It is all about defining the bounds. I tried another zoom level and picked bound values more precise (I used road number icons as reference points - top left and bottom right corners). Red points represent stations. See screenshot http://i.stack.imgur.com/fTv3y.png

Comment: yeh it looks exact points. here i am using plain black png. so how can i get that bound points.

Comment: please, give a link to your image

Comment: i've added image in question. the red point which sees in a ocean near florida is actually in a florida. i think longitude is right but latitude is the problem.

Comment: Try OpenStreetMap service, it allows you to export a map region within specific bounds http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=36.3&lon=-91.7&zoom=3&layers=M. Your map isn't detailed, so you can make a layer in photoshop and draw country's border on top and then fill background with black

Comment: If you need to adjust bounds a bit, for example, latitude, change both values (top and bottom) to the same value - this will move points up/down

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to move outside of Google Maps, I would suggest you give a try to jVector Map, a JavaScript based maps solution using jQuery.

Below is the code sample, that shows the unemployment rate in US:

The below Source Code will help you get this output:

```
$(function(){
  $.getJSON('/data/us-unemployment.json', function(data){
    var val = 2009;
        statesValues = jvm.values.apply({}, jvm.values(data.states)),
        metroPopValues = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], jvm.values(data.metro.population)),
        metroUnemplValues = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], jvm.values(data.metro.unemployment));

    $('#world-map-gdp').vectorMap({
      map: 'us_aea_en',
      markers: data.metro.coords,
      series: {
        markers: [{
          attribute: 'fill',
          scale: ['#FEE5D9', '#A50F15'],
          values: data.metro.unemployment[val],
          min: jvm.min(metroUnemplValues),
          max: jvm.max(metroUnemplValues)
        },{
          attribute: 'r',
          scale: [5, 20],
          values: data.metro.population[val],
          min: jvm.min(metroPopValues),
          max: jvm.max(metroPopValues)
        }],
        regions: [{
          scale: ['#DEEBF7', '#08519C'],
          attribute: 'fill',
          values: data.states[val],
          min: jvm.min(statesValues),
          max: jvm.max(statesValues)
        }]
      },
      onMarkerLabelShow: function(event, label, index){
        label.html(
          ''+data.metro.names[index]+''+
          'Population: '+data.metro.population[val][index]+''+
          'Unemployment rate: '+data.metro.unemployment[val][index]+'%'
        );
      },
      onRegionLabelShow: function(event, label, code){
        label.html(
          ''+label.html()+''+
          'Unemployment rate: '+data.states[val][code]+'%'
        );
      }
    });

    var mapObject = $('#world-map-gdp').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');

    $("#slider").slider({
      value: val,
      min: 2005,
      max: 2009,
      step: 1,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        val = ui.value;
        mapObject.series.regions[0].setValues(data.states[ui.value]);
        mapObject.series.markers[0].setValues(data.metro.unemployment[ui.value]);
        mapObject.series.markers[1].setValues(data.metro.population[ui.value]);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The Above Code will render the map like below:

[image: USA unemployment]
[**LINK TO JVECTORMAP**](http://jvectormap.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just a scaling issue?

Put a flat image in, and then plot the points exactly as you would normally but scaled.

Ie.

```
h_scale=(real_america_width/image_america_width)
v_scale=(real_america_height/image_america_height)
lat = lat_from_json*h_scale)
lon = lon_from_json*v_scale)
```

Then just plonk the markers.

Sorry it isn't real code but I have no idea what language you want it in. End of the day, it's a fairly simple method.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to android google map api is google Static Maps API(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).                          Just get a map image with ur coordinates and point other coordinates relatively.